# Inset uneven after Ctrl-A S

Tags: interface

Is there a way to manually enter the parameters for inset distance and depth?  I have normalized my scale but the inset is still uneven.

For example, any way to specify a distance from a plane border.

Also, how do I get to the Operators options for inset. If I go into Inset no operator options appear.

Comment: You should be able to input the distance numerically in the tool panel. (Press T to open the tool panel, or press F6 to show a floating window for active tools).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations - but no response F6.  The Tool panel and Transform panels are visible (by pressing N).  If I go into Inset Faces, there is panel that opens with the option to Toggle Edit Mode.  If I move the mouse, a very uneven inset is drawn that is nothing like the shape that I am trying to apply the Inset to.